# Как прикрепить к низу блока с картинкой полосу с текстом?

Tags: css, css3

Как можно прикрепить вот такую полосу с текстом внутри к имеющемуся блоку с картинкой, также уже к ней самой добавить выпирающий треугольник?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вариантов куча... Покажи верстку...

Comment: Блок с картинкой внутри просто..

Comment: Ну вот и покажи, как ты его сверстал. Что именно не получается?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант..

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}

.block > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Относится к нижнему блоку */
/* Стили самого блока */
.block .bottom {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fbfaf8;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

/* Стили для уголка */
.block .bottom::before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fbfaf8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -16px;
}

/* Стили заголовка */
.block .bottom .title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #bfb09c;
}

/* Стили описания */
.block .bottom .des {
  display: block;
  color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<!-- Допустим ваша вёрстка выглядит вот так -->
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/A7kTM1M.png">
  <!-- Добавить следующее -->
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="title">Usus Legentis Videntur</div>
    <div class="des">Photography, Holiday</div>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------ -->
</div>
```

---

На будущее, когда будете задавать похожие вопросы, добавляйте свой код, на основе этого вы получите более точный, для вас, ответ.

Comment: Хороший ответ (+)